# AssertionError: Checkbox: u'%' - was not toggled in SST Python

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox, sst

I have a checkbox on my webpage that starts in a state of false and I want to use SST to toggle it to true. However, I keep receiving the `AssertionError: Checkbox u'%' - was not toggled, value remains: False`. I have used both `set_checkbox_value()` and `toggle_checkbox()` and receive the same error with both. My line of code right now reads `toggle_checkbox(id_or_elem='cbLFav')`. The stacktrace is:

```
DEBUG:SST:Checkbox: u'cbLFav' - was not toggled, value remains: False
DEBUG:SST:Stopping browser
FAIL (63.522 secs)
======================================================================
FAIL: ..04fitness-tracker
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Brenda\brenda_test\ENV\lib\site-packages\sst\cases.py", line 20
7, in run_test_script
exec self.code in self.context
File ".\04fitness-tracker.py", line 24, in <module>
toggle_checkbox(id_or_elem='cbLFav')
File "C:\Users\Brenda\brenda_test\ENV\lib\site-packages\sst\actions.py", line
467, in toggle_checkbox
_raise(msg)
File "C:\Users\Brenda\brenda_test\ENV\lib\site-packages\sst\actions.py", line
118, in _raise
raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Checkbox: u'cbLFav' - was not toggled, value remains: False
```

When using `set_checkbox_value`, my code looks like `set_checkbox_value('cbLFav', True)`. Any idea why this isn't setting the value to True?

Code looks like: `<input type="checkbox" value="true" class="np_add_fav_cb" id="cbLFav" name="fav">`

Comment: Have you tried with passing the object instead of `id`. Something like `set_checkbox_value(get_element_by_css("[id='cbLFav']"), True)`?

Comment: @Saifur, I just tried that with both the `set_checkbox_value()` and `toggle_checkbox()` and still receiving the same error.

Comment: Yes I want to see if the **Exact** code I provided worked

Comment: That was the exact code I used and still received the error: `AssertionError: Checkbox: u'cbLFav' - was not toggled, value remains: False`

Comment: A possible workaround can be `click_element('cbLFav', wait=True) assert_checkbox_value('cbLFav', True)`

Comment: Well, and here is another thing. Looking at the html I see it is already selected and you are trying to check it again and that might the possible reason of failure. Pass `False` and see if that uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: I tried both scenarios and the last one gave me `AssertionError: Checkbox: u'cbLFav' - Has Value: False.` I'm beginning to wonder if I've just uncovered a defect in the code I'm testing rather than this being a test case issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66673/discussion-between-saifur-and-brenda).